# Vertically center a cell in tables and ensure that \hline doesn't span across all cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have the following table:

[image]

As you can see all the elemnts are aligned to the top. I want all the cell elemnts to be aligned to the center. I ultimately want my result to look like this.
[image]

My MWE is:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.25cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|c|c|ccc|c|}\hline
$X^{-1}$S & ${A}$ & {} & $y$&{}&{}&{}&$r_{1}$\\[5ex]\hdashline
$A^T$ & $-Y^{-1}Z$ & {} & $x$&{}&{}&{}&$r_{2}$\\[10ex] \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I alos want to \hline and \hdashline to not go  over few columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matrices can be written also in TikZ! There the borders and dashed lines (if you persist to have) is easy to drawn:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt,
    every node/.style = {minimum height=9mm},
    column sep=3mm
                    ]
    \matrix (m1) [draw, matrix of math nodes]
{
X^{-1}S & A         \\
A^T     & -Y^{-1}Z  \\
};
\node (m2) [right=of m1] {$\cdot$};
    \matrix (m3) [right=of m2,draw, matrix of math nodes]
{
y   \\ 
x   \\
};
\node (m4) [right=of m3] {$=$};
    \matrix (m5) [right=of m4,draw, matrix of math nodes]
{    
r_{1}   \\ 
r_{2}   \\
};
\draw[dashed]   (m1.west) -- (m1.east)  (m1.north) -- (m1.south)  
                (m3.west) -- (m3.east)
                (m5.west) -- (m5.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In case, that you like to have asymmetric matrices layout or enclosed by square brackets (what is usual notation of matrices):

[image]

For this two cases the above MWE need minor changes (`in code indicated by %<--`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt,
    every node/.style = {minimum height=9mm},
    column sep=3mm,
    nodes in empty cells% <-- added
                    ]
    \matrix (m1) [draw, matrix of math nodes]
{
X^{-1}S & A         \\
        &           \\% <-- added
A^T     & -Y^{-1}Z  \\
        &           \\% <-- added
};
\node (m2) [right=of m1] {$\cdot$};
    \matrix (m3) [right=of m2,draw, matrix of math nodes]
{
y   \\
    \\% <-- added
x   \\
    \\% <-- added
};
\node (m4) [right=of m3] {$=$};
    \matrix (m5) [right=of m4,draw, matrix of math nodes]
{
r_{1}   \\
        \\% <-- added
r_{2}   \\
        \\% <-- added
};
\draw[dashed]   (m1-1-1.south west) -- (m1-1-1.south -| m1.east)  
                (m1.north) -- (m1.south)
                %
                (m3-1-1.south west) -- (m3-1-1.south east -| m3.east)
                (m5-1-1.south west) -- (m5-1-1.south east -| m5.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=1mm,% <-- changed
    every node/.style = {minimum height=11mm},% <-- enlarged
    column sep=3mm,
                    ]
    \matrix (m1) [matrix of math nodes,%
                  {left delimiter=[},{right delimiter=]}]% <-- added
{
X^{-1}S & A         \\ 
A^T     & -Y^{-1}Z  \\ 
};
\node (m2) [right=of m1] {$\cdot$};
    \matrix (m3) [right=of m2,
                  matrix of math nodes,%
                  {left delimiter=[},{right delimiter=]}]% <-- added
{
y   \\ 
x   \\ 
};
\node (m4) [right=of m3] {$=$};
    \matrix (m5) [right=of m4,
                  matrix of math nodes,%
                  {left delimiter=[},{right delimiter=]}]% <-- added
{
r_{1}   \\ 
r_{2}   \\ 
};
\draw[dashed]   (m1.west) -- (m1.east)  (m1.north) -- (m1.south)
                (m3.west) -- (m3.east)
                (m5.west) -- (m5.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use a `tabular` environment for material that appears to be entirely in math mode; instead, I'd use three separate, side-by-side `array` enviroments. I also wouldn't provide (dashed *or* solid) horizontal and vertical lines. Such lines are nothing more but visual "crutches" which seem hardly needed when dealing with 2x2 matrices and 2-element column vectors.

Something like the following may well be all your readers really need (feel free to modify the settings of `\arraycolsep` and `\arraystretch`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{10pt}    % default: 5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5} % default: 1
\begin{array}{|CC|} \hline
X^{-1}S & A         \\ 
A^T     & -Y^{-1}Z  \\[1ex] \hline
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}{|C|}\hline
y \\ x \\[1ex] \hline
\end{array}
\quad{=}\quad
\begin{array}{|C|}\hline
r_{1} \\ r_{2} \\[1ex] \hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a tabular environment I utilized the `array` `booktabs` `multirow` and `arydshln` packages and used used `\multirow` `\cline` and `\cdashline`. I am sure this is not the most elegant way, but it does make the tale.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}|c|}
\cline{1-2}
\cline{4-4}
\cline{6-6}
&&&&&\\[1pt]
$X^{-1}$Z & ${A}$ & &$y$&\multirow{6}{*}{=} & $r_{2}$\\[1ex]
\cdashline{1-2}
\cdashline{4-4}
\cdashline{6-6}
&&&&&\\[3ex]
$A^T$ & $-Y^{-1}Z$ & & $x$& &  $r_{2}$\\[7ex]
\cline{1-2}
\cline{4-4}
\cline{6-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Note: In your MWE you used an S in the top left cell, but in your "ideal" picture it was a Z. I used a Z, but it is easy enough to change. Also I did not center the items in the cells (vertically) all the way, because they are not fully centered in the "ideal" table picture.